# How do I left join a string List and fill in missing values with zeros

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following example with test data:

```
class Program
{
    private class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> types = new List<string>{ "TypeA", "TypeB", "TypeC" };

        List<Item> data = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { Id = 1, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2017"), Type = "TypeA" },
            new Item { Id = 2, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2017"), Type = "TypeB" },
            new Item { Id = 3, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("01/02/2017"), Type = "TypeA" },
            new Item { Id = 4, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("01/02/2017"), Type = "TypeB" },
            new Item { Id = 5, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("01/03/2017"), Type = "TypeA" },
            new Item { Id = 6, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("01/03/2017"), Type = "TypeB" },
            new Item { Id = 7, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("01/04/2017"), Type = "TypeA" },
            new Item { Id = 8, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("01/04/2017"), Type = "TypeB" },
            new Item { Id = 9, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("01/05/2017"), Type = "TypeA" },
            new Item { Id = 10, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("01/05/2017"), Type = "TypeB" },

            new Item { Id = 11, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2017"), Type = "TypeA" },
            new Item { Id = 12, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2017"), Type = "TypeB" },
            new Item { Id = 13, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2017"), Type = "TypeC" },
            new Item { Id = 14, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("02/02/2017"), Type = "TypeA" },
            new Item { Id = 15, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("02/02/2017"), Type = "TypeB" },
            new Item { Id = 16, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("02/02/2017"), Type = "TypeC" },
            new Item { Id = 17, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("02/03/2017"), Type = "TypeA" },
            new Item { Id = 18, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("02/03/2017"), Type = "TypeB" },
            new Item { Id = 19, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("02/03/2017"), Type = "TypeC" },
            new Item { Id = 20, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("02/05/2017"), Type = "TypeB" },
            new Item { Id = 21, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("02/05/2017"), Type = "TypeC" },

            new Item { Id = 22, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("03/01/2017"), Type = "TypeC" },
            new Item { Id = 23, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("03/01/2017"), Type = "TypeB" },
            new Item { Id = 24, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("03/01/2017"), Type = "TypeC" },
            new Item { Id = 25, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("03/02/2017"), Type = "TypeA" },
            new Item { Id = 26, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("03/02/2017"), Type = "TypeB" },
            new Item { Id = 27, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("03/02/2017"), Type = "TypeC" },
            new Item { Id = 28, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("03/03/2017"), Type = "TypeB" },
            new Item { Id = 29, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("03/03/2017"), Type = "TypeB" },
            new Item { Id = 30, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("03/03/2017"), Type = "TypeC" },
            new Item { Id = 31, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("03/05/2017"), Type = "TypeB" },
            new Item { Id = 32, CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("03/05/2017"), Type = "TypeC" },
        };

        var result = data
            .GroupBy(d => new
            {
                d.Type,
                d.CreatedDate.Year,
                d.CreatedDate.Month
            })
            .Select(i => new
            {
                Month = new DateTime(i.Key.Year, i.Key.Month, 1),
                i.Key.Type,
                Count = i.Count()
            })
            .OrderBy(o=>o.Month)
            .ThenBy(o=>o.Type);

        foreach (var r in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}: {2}", r.Month, r.Type, r.Count);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

With the result of:

> 2017-01-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeA: 5
>
> 2017-01-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeB: 5
>
> 2017-02-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeA: 3
>
> 2017-02-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeB: 4
>
> 2017-02-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeC: 4
>
> 2017-03-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeA: 1
>
> 2017-03-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeB: 5
>
> 2017-03-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeC: 5

However what I am stuck on is I want to use the

```
List<string> types
```

so I can get the following result:

> 2017-01-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeA: 5
>
> 2017-01-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeB: 5
>
> **2017-01-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeC: 0**
>
> 2017-02-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeA: 3
>
> 2017-02-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeB: 4
>
> 2017-02-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeC: 4
>
> 2017-03-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeA: 1
>
> 2017-03-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeB: 5
>
> 2017-03-01 12:00:00 AM - TypeC: 5

I want each Month to have all types (in this case 3) and any missing types will default of zero.

Comment: The solution isn't to use Left Outer Join.  You first have to create a blank template  with DateTime, Type, and value = 0.  Then join the actual data with the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jdweng mentioned in comment, to Join, you would need to create a Template List, So, IMHO, an easier workaround in this particular case would be to leave out Join altogether and fill in missing Data.

```
var result = data
            .GroupBy(d => new
            {
                d.Type,
                d.CreatedDate.Year,
                d.CreatedDate.Month
            })
            .Select(i => new
            {
                Month = new DateTime(i.Key.Year, i.Key.Month, 1),
                i.Key.Type,
                Count = i.Count()
            })
            .ToList();


        var dateList = result.Select(x=>x.Month).Distinct().ToList();
        void GenerateEmptyEntries()
        {
            foreach(var date in dateList)
            {
                foreach(var type in types)
                {
                    if(!result.Any(x=>x.Month == date && x.Type == type))
                    {
                        result.Add(new {Month = date, Type = type, Count = 0});
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        GenerateEmptyEntries();
        foreach (var r in result.OrderBy(o=>o.Month)
            .ThenBy(o=>o.Type))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}: {2}", r.Month, r.Type, r.Count);
        }
```

Output

```
01-01-2017 00:00:00 - TypeA: 5
01-01-2017 00:00:00 - TypeB: 5
01-01-2017 00:00:00 - TypeC: 0
01-02-2017 00:00:00 - TypeA: 3
01-02-2017 00:00:00 - TypeB: 4
01-02-2017 00:00:00 - TypeC: 4
01-03-2017 00:00:00 - TypeA: 1
01-03-2017 00:00:00 - TypeB: 5
01-03-2017 00:00:00 - TypeC: 5
```